# ERORR:warning comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user,pass;

    printf("New Username:\n");
    scanf("%d",&user);
    printf("New Password:\n");
    scanf("%d",&pass);
    printf("Type your username:\n");
    scanf("%d",&user);
    if ("%d"==&user)
    {
        printf("Username is good !!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Username is not good");
    }
    printf("type your password:\n ");
    scanf("%d",&pass);
    if ("%d"==pass)
    {
        printf("The password is good");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The password is not good");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help give me warning says:warning comparison between pointer and integer why?????
what is wrong??

> warning comparison between pointer and integer 
>   comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior

Comment: `if ("%d"==&user)`, I mean , really?

Comment: its not good or what?? :)

Comment: it's meaningless - you are comparing a control string with the address of variable - which makes no sense. And because you mixed up English with some language (Password noua?) it's harder to help/

Comment: why you laughing ... I am new in C ..mostly I work in python .. :)

Comment: You really need to check the value returned from `scanf()`.  Right now, you have no idea if any of your calls to `scanf()` actually read data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors.

```
if ("%d"==pass)
```

Here you are comparing value of pass variable to the string literal. And here it is wrong and also not required.

and

```
if ("%d"==&user)
```

Here you are comparing addrerss of `user` variable to the string literal. And here it is wrong and also not required.

---

I have tried to modify your code as  some level. I think this is what you want.

And yes for username you need to use `char array` for storing name and `strcmp` to matching them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_org,pass_org;
    int user,pass; 

    // First store original username and password
    printf("Orignal Username:\n");
    scanf("%d",&user_org);
    printf("Original Password:\n");
    scanf("%d",&pass_org);


    // Check for username
    printf("Type your username:\n");
    scanf("%d",&user);
    if (user_org == user)
    {
        printf("Username match");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Username is incorrect");
    }


    // check for password
    printf("type your password:\n ");
    scanf("%d",&pass);
    if (pass_org == pass)
    {
        printf("The password match");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("The password is not correct");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My dear down voter please care to comment, I love to learn from my own mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ("%d"==pass)
```

Comparing a string literal to an integer? Why? That makes no sense. Your integer pass can never be equal to a string literal `"%d"` (which is `{'%','d','\0'}` btw)

That check is completly superflous.

```
if ("%d"==&user)
```

Thats even worse, and thats where your warning comes from. You are comparing a pointer to a `int` with a string literal.

If you want to check if your username and pass are in fact integers, you don't need to do that, since `scanf` does that for you.

Comment: @KevinIT no problem. Please refrain from asking questions before debugging in future.